# One model and Many edit views

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model I named User, and I want use two different Views to edit it: the usual **edit** view and another view I called **edit_profile**.

I had no problem in creating routing, controller and views: I added edit_profile and update_profile views, and I added on routes.rb the line:

```
map.resources :users ,:member => {:edit_profile => :get, :update_profile => :put}
```

The problem is: when I submit the form in edit_profile and some error occur in some input fields, rails reload the edit_path page instead of edit_profile_path page !
This is the form on edit_profile.html.erb

```
  form_for(:user, @user, :url => {:action => :update_profile}, :html => { :method => :put}  ) do |f|

    f.text_field :description
    f.text_area :description
    f.error_message_on :description

    ....
    ....

    f.submit 'Update profile'
```

After clicking Update profile, if input errors occur I want to show edit_profile view instead of edit view

Where is the problem ?
Do You have some ideas ?
many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller's action (the `edit` action, I assume) will need to know whether it has been reached via the normal `edit` page or the `edit_profile` page. You can use a hidden field named, perhaps, `profile` to post a breadcrumb that will tell it that. By doing this, you can redirect conditionally based on the existence of a `profile` param.

A cleaner way is to create a new action called `edit_profile` and extract the editing code to a common method that is called from both `edit` and `edit_profile` let the public methods handle any redirects.

Answer (score 2):

Adding extra actions to a RESTful controller is often a code smell, an indication that there's a better way to model what you're trying to do. In this case, profile is really a sub-resource of user:

```
map.resources :users, :has_one => :profile
```

making your profile routes like

```
GET /users/1/profile # show
GET /users/1/profile/edit #edit
PUT /users/1/profile # update
DELETE /users/1/profile #destroy
```

You will have a separate ProfilesController for these actions... much cleaner.

How you model the data is up to you, (you don't have to have a one-to-one correlation between your models and your controllers!), but in this case I'd probably use ActiveRecord's aggregations to model the relationship between User and Profile. Think of it as an embedded has_one: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Aggregations/ClassMethods.html

Note that adding additional actions to RESTful controllers isn't always "wrong" ... its up to you to determine when its appropriate to split off the new actions into a separate resource. In this case, however, I think it's very clear-cut!

Comment: Agreed! My answer was more along the lines of a workable hack, which is unfortunately the way I tend to work at this point. But what you describe is certainly the way to go.

Comment: In my case I didn't create another model because the user profile is very tiny. But if the profile should grows up I will follow your advice.Thank you the clarification

Answer (score 1):

Take a look in your user_controller file's update method. That's where submitting the edit form takes you. You'll see there that if the record can't be updated, it redirects back to the edit method.

One way to do what you want is to make your edit_profile form point to a new method, perhaps called update_profile, which is the same as the edit method but redirects to edit_profile when the record can't be saved.

Perhaps a better and DRY-er way to do it would be to pass a parameter from the edit_profile form that you can detect in your existing update method to differentiate between update attempts coming from edit / edit_profile.

Good luck!